# AdUser to Domain POWERSHELL

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I´m trying to pass all Information for a ad new user over Powershell and if i make copy-paste this ok but if i try the same comands in a script fails.

```
#####Write-Host "Im trying a connections to your AD DS"
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName DC -Credential dd\administrator
Start-Sleep -s 5 

##### my vars
$name = Read-host "Vorname?" 
$surname = Read-Host "Nachname?"
$password = "pa$$w0rd" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force


#####adding User
New-ADUser -Name "$surname $name" `
-Surname "$surname" `
-GivenName "$name" `
-SamAccountName "$surname" `
-UserPrincipalName "$surname@dd.zz" `
-AccountPassword $password 
-ChangePasswordAtLogon $True `
-Enabled $True `
-Path 'OU=MUC,OU=User,DC=dd,DC=zz' `
-OtherAttributes @{'mail'="$name.$surname@dd.com"}
```

error code:

```
New-ADUser : Zugriff verweigert
In Zeile:18 Zeichen:1
+ New-ADUser -Name "$surname $name" `
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (CN=fromtheother...C=dd,DC=zz:String) [New-ADUser], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADUser
```

Comment: you are getting an access denied return error. are you running the script from within an elevated shell? do you use the same user? did you try adding `-Credential dd\administrator` to the `New-ADUser` cmdlet?

Comment: The error message is that you don't have permissions on the organizational unit `OU=MUC,OU=User,DC=dd,DC=zz`. This command will show you the groups\users who have Create Child in that OU: `((Get-Acl 'AD:\OU=MUC,OU=User,DC=dd,DC=zz').Access | Where-Object {([int]$_.activedirectoryrights % 2) -eq 1}).IdentityReference`

Answer (score -1):

Try opening Powershell ISE as the administrator account for active directory (CTL+SHIFT+RIGHT-Click -> Run-As) then opening the script from that interface and run it. This should allow you to run it with the correct permissions.

If you are on a server doing this with the correct permissions. Run ISE as administrator and then open the script and run for the correct permissions.